# Sending a dummy variable to a function as a compound literal

Tags: c

Let's say I have the following I'm using to call a function:

```
Item dummy;
while (!QueueIsEmpty(pq))
    DeQueue(pq, &dummy);
```

Is there a way to put the `dummy` parameter into the call itself? Something like:

```
while (!QueueIsEmpty(pq))
    DeQueue(pq, &(Item)NULL);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `DeQueue(pq, &(Item) NULL)`. You might mean: `DeQueue(pq,(Item *) NULL)` or simply: `DeQueue(pq, NULL)`?

Comment: @CraigEstey the dequeue copies the value to `Item`, but in this case I don't need it. I guess if it copies it to a pointer, then it needs a valid address then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't valid C [AFAICT]

From my top comment, you might mean: `DeQueue(pq,(Item *) NULL)` or simply: `DeQueue(pq, NULL)`?

You're trying to create a compound literal, but it's being initialized from a [NULL] *pointer*.

---

Here's the test program I created:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
} Queue;

typedef struct {
    int y;
    int z;
} Item;

int
QueueIsEmpty(Queue * pq)
{

    return 0;
}

void
DeQueue(Queue * pq, Item * item)
{
}

int
main(void)
{

    Item dummy;
    Queue *pq = NULL;

    while (!QueueIsEmpty(pq))
        DeQueue(pq, &dummy);

    // Is there a way to put the dummy parameter into the call itself?
    // Something like:

    while (!QueueIsEmpty(pq))
        DeQueue(pq, &(Item) NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the output of `gcc`:

```
x.c:38:3: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

Here's the output of `clang`:

```
x.c:38:16: error: used type 'Item' where arithmetic or pointer type is required
```

---

What you may have wanted is:

```
DeQueue(pq, &(Item) { 0 })
```

But, passing that is a bit of [too much] trickery.

Personally, I've never done something like that. I've always just passed down a NULL pointer.

If you *do* really want a "dummy" parameter, I'd do the `Item dummy;` thing [vs the compound literal]. It's actually faster because you don't add the overhead of the initialization.

To me, the compound literal is getting "too cute"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the method dequeues an object and copies its value to the dummy variable. Where would you expect it to be copied without providing a place to copy it to?
Do you want to just throw it away and clear the queue this way?

If so I would expect that you have to pass it inside unless there is another method that just clears the queue without even copying it. Maybe some clear method.

Answer (score 1):

If the function requires the address of a valid object, you can pass in the address of a compound literal:

```
DeQueue(pq, &((Item){0}) );
```